# US and UK format in datetime output

Tags: c#, datetime

C#:

I want to get date time object dependent to culture specific.

Input can be in **dd/mm/yyyy** or **mm/dd/yyyy**.

Output should be culture specific.

If input : en-US and format of string is (dd/mm/yyyy ,  mm/dd/yyyy)

Output should be MM/dd/yyyy

If input : en-GB format of string is (dd/mm/yyyy ,  mm/dd/yyyy)

Output should be dd/MM/yyyy

Please provide solution in C# and provide only  when both scenarios exists in solution

Comment: StackOverflow isn't for outsourcing code... Consider trying this yourself, and asking a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: Try to look ToString() method over DateTime Strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get date time object dependent to culture specific.

There's no such concept. Even the *calendar system* isn't part of `DateTime`. The same `DateTime` value is used to represent a single value regardless of culture.

However, you can specify the culture when you *format* a `DateTime`, converting it to text. For example:

```
DateTime dateTime = ...;
string text = dateTime.ToString("d", culture); // d = short date format
```

Now if your input is in *either* `dd/MM/yyyy` *or* `MM/dd/yyyy` format, then you've fundamentally got a problem. You won't know whether 06/07/2015 is July 6th or June 7th, unless you have other information to help you. Again, if you know that it's the short date format of a specific culture, then you can use

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "d", culture);
```